# Who is the character in a suite at the DS-1 Orbital Station overbridge?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, a-new-hope

In *Star Wars: A New Hope*, almost at the end of the film, there is scene at the DS-1 Orbital Station overbridge where Grand Moff Tarkin orders one of his aides to fire the superlaser when ready. In that scene, at the left of the screen, it can be seen a standing person, with bald crown from behind, wearing what appears to be a suit and shoes. As far as I know, all of the Death Star commanders wear military attires with belts snugly adjusted and tall boots, thus, I ask, who is that guy?

[image: Still of Star Wars A New Hope DS1 Command Deck]

[image: Detail of Still of Star Wars A New Hope DS1 Command Deck]

Here a still of Tarkin and Motti in the DS-1 overbridge at the moment when a Death Star intercom voice says:

> Rebel base, one minute and closing.

In other words, one minute to have the Rebel base in range and having Tarkin saying to his aide:

> You may fire when ready.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Conan Antonio Motti](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Conan_Antonio_Motti)

#### *Logical Speculation*

Based on hair coloring and the balding patch, it appears to be Motti.

[image]

There is evidence that Motti was on the same set with Tarkin and we know that Motti was the one to whom Tarkin gave the directive to commence firing the Death Star the first time against Alderaan and that they are on the same bridge (the [Overbridge](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Overbridge)):

```
                                   TARKIN
                     There. You see Lord Vader, she can 
                     be reasonable.
                          (addressing Motti)
                     Continue with the operation. You may 
                     fire when ready.
```

[image]

so it's reasonable to presume that he was also directing Motti the second time when readying to fire on the Rebel Base.

[image]

Behind the scenes image of Motti and Tarkin on set

[image]

Comment: one note worth making, in the second image, we see Motti with the high boots on, which the character in the question is not wearing. However, in the same image we also see Peter Cushing wearing his famous slippers due to the boots being uncomfortable. Thus, we might not put toooo much emphasis on footwear for character identification. Motti being neary out of shot and in the dark, the actor may have likewise found the boots problematic and opted out as well for that scene

Comment: Could it not be Hurst Romodi: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hurst_Romodi ? The bald head and wispy hair seem more likely than being Motti.

Comment: Romodi is nearly bald @SpaceWolf1701 - character in question appears to have mostly a full head of hair (in comparison) - also there is no evidence (that I've found) that indicates Romodi was on that set, as opposed to Motti (as I've shown). Could be - sure? Likely - eh...I don't think so imo

Comment: Hmm. I see what you mean.